# Mongoid: eager loading relations in parent and its subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, eager-loading

I'm using subclasses in mongoid and I would like to eager load relations of both the parent and its subclasses.

```
class Event
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :modifier
end

class Fixture < Event
   belongs_to :club
end
```

When I run `Event.includes(:modifier, :club)` I get:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidIncludes:
Problem:
Invalid includes directive: Event.includes(:modifier, :club)
Summary:
Eager loading in Mongoid only supports providing arguments to 
Event.includes that are the names of relations on the Event model, 
and only supports one     level of eager loading. (ie, eager
loading associations not on the Event but one step away via 
another relation is not allowed.
Resolution:
Ensure that each parameter passed to Event.includes is a valid name
of a relation on the Event model. These are: "modifier".
```

The error message is reasonable but I'd like to know if there is a workaround, short of running a separate query on each class?

I'd like to be able to also chain further criteria, i.e. `Event.includes(:modifier, :club).desc(:updated_at)` rather than sorting the result array in rails.

versions: Mongoid v3.16 & Rails 3.2.15

---

Edit: I'd better make it clearer what it is I want.

I want all events and all fixtures documents. 
I also want all their relations: the modifiers on Events and Fixtures, and the clubs on Fixtures.
And I want those related documents to be retrieved from mongo all at once, i.e. typically done through 'eager loading' using the '.includes()' method .
There will be further subclasses, i.e. `class Election < Events`, `class Seminar < Events`. So I'd like to avoid querying each subclass separately.
I'd also like to chain further criteria, such as `desc(:updated_at)`.

Comment: What is the relationship between event and player?

Comment: Thanks @kdeisz, :player should be :club - updated.

Comment: What's the relationship between Event and Fixture?

Comment: They are not relations; Fixture is subclass of Event, and their documents are stored in the same collection, 'events'. I've updated the example to make it clear that Event is a MongoId model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you try to do, but I guess this could solve your problem.

```
Event.where(:modifier_id.ne => nil, :club_id.ne => nil).desc(:updated_at)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Your code will return all Fixtures but no Events, and does not eager load the relations. But I want all Events and their modifiers, and all Fixtures and their respective modifiers and clubs (see 'Eager Loading' in http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html)

Comment: Did you try "Fixture.includes(:modifier, :club)"? Fixture extends Event, so modifier is a valid attr on Fixture.

Comment: I suspect I've failed to explain the problem clearly enough - I'll update the question shortly.

Answer (score 0):

so far MongoID doesn't support nested document eager loading. you better check out this [gem](https://github.com/ElMassimo/mongoid_includes)